# Why does assigning a value to double underscore __ break the behavior of single underscore _ in ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

I have been playing with the [output caching system](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system) in IPython and noticed some strange behavior, giving unexpected results when using the single underscore `_` to obain the previous output.

Before writing up this question I didn't know about the output caching system implemented in IPython and figured I should use a double underscore `__` as a dummy variable, if I wanted to use the previous output by accessing the special `_`-Variable.

Consider the following session:

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: 2*3                                                                               
Out[1]: 6

In [2]: 4 + _  # expect 10, OK                                                            
Out[2]: 10

In [3]: __, something = 1, 2                                                              

In [4]: 3*3                                                                               
Out[4]: 9

In [5]: 3 + _  # expect 3+9=12, but:                                                      
Out[5]: 13
```

As you can see above, after assigning a value to `__`, using `_` does not give the expected result.

After reading the references linked earlier, I know I probably just shouldn't mess with `_`, `__` or `___`. Does assigning one of these simply freeze all others?
The documentation does not hint at these problems. Also, I find this highly counterintuitive since a regular python shell behaves differently. (After going through the example above in a regular shell, the final output is as expected!)

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: Note, this is version-dependent - it does work in IPython 5.8.0 at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IPython have (among others) 3 specific variables: `_`, `__`, and `___`, 
Every time you do an execution they got moved around; `_` -> `__`, `__` -> `___`, `___` -> discarded, and last result -> `_`

*If* one of these variables get assigned; then the rotation stops.

```
In [1]: 1
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: 2  # _:1, __:'', ___:''
Out[2]: 2

In [3]: 3  # _:2, __:1, ___:'' 
Out[3]: 3

In [4]: ___ ='something', # _:3, __:2, ___:1

In [5]: __ # still gonna be 2
Out[5]: 2

In [6]: __ # still gonna be 2 again
Out[6]: 2

In [7]: _ # still 3
Out[7]: 3
```

It's worth discussing but it's quite tough to modify; it is relatively hard to figure out what is meant and wether the user had "modified" `_`, `__` or `___`;

In the above example, replace `"something"` by `1` and because `(1 is 1) == True`, then IPython won't "detect" you've assigned one of the underscore and resume shifting things around.

Comment: Using other editors such as IDLE or sublime, the only builtin variables are the "magic objects" like `__init__`, `__name__`, and `__doc__`